# Scale winforms controls with window size

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to scale all controls in my program (the ones in the tabcontrol too) when user resizes the window.
I know how to resize the controls, but i wanted my program to have everything scaled, so the ui i easier to read

i am not a good explainer, so here's a reference picture:
[image: scaled controls (not resized)]

I have seen a lot of discussions about resizing the controls, but they are not very helpful.
can i achieve this effect in winforms?

Comment: Some hints. Start by recording the position and size of the windows and all the controls. When the user makes a change, do your calculations based on those original coordinates and the current window size. That way, integer quantisization errors won't accumulate of the user does this a lot (or does it slowly). I'd resist the urge to try to animate what's going on as it's going on. Instead, consider something like `ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame` to give some non-flickering UI feedback. Get used to doing some frustrating simple math

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to **scale winforms controls with window size** is to use nested `TableLayoutPanel` controls and set the rows and columns to use percent rather than absolute sizing.

[image: nested table layout panels]

---

Then, place your controls in the cells and anchor them on all four sides. For buttons that have a background image set to `BackgroundImageLayout = Stretch` this is all you need to do. However, controls that use text may require a custom means to scale the font. For example, you're using ComboBox controls where size is a function of the font not the other way around. To compensate for this, these actual screenshots utilize an extension to do a binary search that changes the font size until a target control height is reached.

[image: resizing performance]

---

The basic idea is to respond to `TableLayoutPanel` size changes by setting a watchdog timer, and when the timer expires iterate the control tree to apply the `BinarySearchFontSize` extension. You may want to [clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/scaling-controls-globally.git) the code I used to test this answer and experiment for yourself to see how the pieces fit together.

Something *like* this would work but you'll probably want to do more testing than I did.

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static float BinarySearchFontSize(this Control control, float containerHeight)
    {
        float
            vertical = BinarySearchVerticalFontSize(control, containerHeight),
            horizontal = BinarySearchHorizontalFontSize(control);
        return Math.Min(vertical, horizontal);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Get a font size that produces control size between 90-100% of available height.
    /// </summary>
    private static float BinarySearchVerticalFontSize(Control control, float containerHeight)
    {
        var name = control.Name;
        switch (name)
        {
            case "comboBox1":
                Debug.WriteLine($"{control.Name}: CONTAINER HEIGHT {containerHeight}");
                break;
        }
        var proto = new TextBox
        {
            Text = "|", // Vertical height independent of text length.
            Font = control.Font
        };
        using (var graphics = proto.CreateGraphics())
        {
            float
                targetMin = 0.9F * containerHeight,
                targetMax = containerHeight,
                min, max;
            min = 0; max = proto.Font.Size * 2;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if(proto.Height < targetMin)
                {
                    // Needs to be bigger
                    min = proto.Font.Size;
                }
                else if (proto.Height > targetMax)
                {
                    // Needs to be smaller
                    max = proto.Font.Size;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
                var newSizeF = (min + max) / 2;
                proto.Font = new Font(control.Font.FontFamily, newSizeF);
                proto.Invalidate();
            }
            return proto.Font.Size;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Get a font size that fits text into available width.
    /// </summary>
    private static float BinarySearchHorizontalFontSize(Control control)
    {
        var name = control.Name;

        // Fine-tuning
        string text;
        if (control is ButtonBase)
        {
            text = "SETTINGS"; // representative max staing
        }
        else
        {
            text = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(control.Text) ? "LOCAL FOLDERS" : control.Text;
        }
        var protoFont = control.Font;
        using(var g = control.CreateGraphics())
        {
            using (var graphics = control.CreateGraphics())
            {
                int width =
                    (control is ComboBox) ?
                        control.Width - SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth :
                        control.Width;
                float
                    targetMin = 0.9F * width,
                    targetMax = width,
                    min, max;
                min = 0; max = protoFont.Size * 2;
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    var sizeF = g.MeasureString(text, protoFont);
                    if (sizeF.Width < targetMin)
                    {
                        // Needs to be bigger
                        min = protoFont.Size;
                    }
                    else if (sizeF.Width > targetMax)
                    {
                        // Needs to be smaller
                        max = protoFont.Size;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    var newSizeF = (min + max) / 2;
                    protoFont = new Font(control.Font.FontFamily, newSizeF);
                }
            }
        }
        return protoFont.Size;
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**

*The essence of my answer is **use nested TableLayoutPanel controls** and I didn't want to take away from that so I had given a reference link to [browse](https://github.com/IVSoftware/scaling-controls-globally.git) the full code. Since `TableLayoutPanel` is not a comprehensive solution without being able to scale the height of ComboBox and other Fonts (which isn't all that trivial for the example shown in the original post) my answer also showed one way to achieve that. In response to the comment below (I do want to provide "enough" info!) here is an appendix showing the MainForm code that calls the extension.*

**Example:**

In the method that loads the main form:

- Iterate the control tree to find all the TableLayoutPanels.
- Attach event handler for the `SizeChanged` event.
- Handle the event by restarting a watchdog timer.
- When the timer expires, _iterate the control tree of each `TableLayoutPanel` to apply the `onAnyCellPaint` method to obtain the cell metrics and call the extension.

By taking this approach, cells and controls can freely be added and/or removed without having to change the scaling engine.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        if(!DesignMode)
        {
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            IterateControlTree(this, (control) =>
            {
                if (control is TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel)
                {
                    tableLayoutPanel.SizeChanged += (sender, e) => _wdtSizeChanged.StartOrRestart();
                }
            });

            _wdtSizeChanged.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.PropertyName!.Equals(nameof(WDT.Busy)) && !_wdtSizeChanged.Busy)
                {
                    IterateControlTree(this, (control) =>
                    {
                        if (control is TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel)
                        {
                            IterateControlTree(tableLayoutPanel, (child) => onAnyCellPaint(tableLayoutPanel, child));
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
        }
        // Induce a size change to initialize the font resizer.
        BeginInvoke(()=> Size = new Size(Width + 1, Height));
        BeginInvoke(()=> Size = new Size(Width - 1, Height));
    }

    // Browse full code sample to see WDT class
    WDT _wdtSizeChanged = new WDT { Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100) };

    SemaphoreSlim _sslimResizing= new SemaphoreSlim(1);
    private void onAnyCellPaint(TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel, Control control)
    {
        if (!DesignMode)
        {
            if (_sslimResizing.Wait(0))
            {
                try
                {
                    var totalVerticalSpace =
                        control.Margin.Top + control.Margin.Bottom +
                        // I'm surprised that the Margin property
                        // makes a difference here but it does!
                        tableLayoutPanel.Margin.Top + tableLayoutPanel.Margin.Bottom +
                        tableLayoutPanel.Padding.Top + tableLayoutPanel.Padding.Bottom;
                    var pos = tableLayoutPanel.GetPositionFromControl(control);
                    int height;
                    float optimal;
                    if (control is ComboBox comboBox)
                    {
                        height = tableLayoutPanel.GetRowHeights()[pos.Row] - totalVerticalSpace;
                        comboBox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
                        optimal = comboBox.BinarySearchFontSize(height);
                        comboBox.Font = new Font(comboBox.Font.FontFamily, optimal);
                        comboBox.ItemHeight = height;
                    }
                    else if((control is TextBoxBase) || (control is ButtonBase))
                    {
                        height = tableLayoutPanel.GetRowHeights()[pos.Row] - totalVerticalSpace;
                        optimal = control.BinarySearchFontSize(height);
                        control.Font = new Font(control.Font.FontFamily, optimal);
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    _sslimResizing.Release();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    internal void IterateControlTree(Control control, Action<Control> fx)
    {
        if (control == null)
        {
            control = this;
        }
        fx(control);
        foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
        {
            IterateControlTree(child, fx);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how can i use this class to get the expected font size?

Comment: The full code can be found in the [clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/scaling-controls-globally.git) link that I referenced in my answer. It's not very complicated but there is a little too much code to show in a StackOverflow post. Please **build and run** the actual project, see whether it does what you want, and if you still have questions about it leave me another comment. Thx!

Comment: The download should compile in VS 2022. If you have VS 2019 or earlier you should let me know as there may be minor syntax tweaks that I need to make to make it backward compatible.